# How to make alias shortcuts for terminal work as root or as exec?

Tags: linux, bash, alias

Let's say I have an alias like this:

```
alias findip='wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//''
```

the output would look like this:

```
matthew@ubuntu:~$ findip
71.141.232.38
matthew@ubuntu:~$
```

So pretty simple, it finds my ip address by connecting to the website and looking for my IP address. Now, if i were to run:

```
tsocks wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address://' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

I would get an output like this:

```
matthew@ubuntu:~$ tsocks wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
77.247.181.162
matthew@ubuntu:~$
```

You will notice that the IP addresses are different. This is because I routed the command through `tsocks`, which I have configured to use tor. But if I were to run:

```
tsocks findip
```

My output would be this:

```
matthew@ubuntu:~$ tsocks findip
exec: 87: findip: not found
matthew@ubuntu:~$
```

[image: My output]

How do I configure my system so that the aliases created apply when I am  running through tsocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias a command to itself, and end the alias with a space:

```
alias exec="exec "
alias sudo="sudo "
alias tsocks="tsocks "
```

With this, bash will automatically expand `tsocks findip` → `tsocks wget -q ...`

As seen in bash's documentation:

```
$ help alias
alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
    ...
    A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
    alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
```

This, however, is *not* related to being root (unless you were talking about `sudo` usage), and *cannot* be done at exec() syscall level (aliases are entirely internal to `bash`).